# 2 same-class objects being instantiated by another same-class object error

Tags: java

I am currently implementing Eight Puzzle problem using A* Algorithm (Hamming) method and have provided code :

```
public class Board
{
int board[][];

public Board()
{
    board = new int[3][3];
}

public void initialise(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5, int n6, int n7, int n8, int n9)
{
    //first row
    board[0][0] = n1;
    board[0][1] = n2;
    board[0][2] = n3;

    //second row
    board[1][0] = n4;
    board[1][1] = n5;
    board[1][2] = n6;

    //third row
    board[2][0] = n7;
    board[2][1] = n8;
    board[2][2] = n9;
}


public int states_out_of_order()
{
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        //Checking if first row is
        //1     2     3
        if(i==0)
        {
            if(board[i][0]!=1)
            {
                count++;
            }

            if(board[i][1]!=2)
            {
                count++;
            }

            if(board[i][2]!=3)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        //Checking if second row is
        //4     5     6
        if(i==1)
        {
            if(board[i][0]!=4)
            {
                count++;
            }

            if(board[i][1]!=5)
            {
                count++;
            }

            if(board[i][2]!=6)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        //Checking if second row is
        //7     8     0
        if(i==2)
        {
            if(board[i][0]!=7)
            {
                count++;
            }

            if(board[i][1]!=8)
            {
                count++;
            }

            if(board[i][2]!=9)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public boolean GoalStateCheck()
{
    //Checking first row
    if(board[0][0]!=1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(board[0][1]!=2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(board[0][2]!=3)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Checking second row
    if(board[1][0]!=4)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(board[1][1]!=5)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(board[1][2]!=6)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Checking third row
    if(board[2][0]!=7)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(board[2][1]!=8)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(board[2][2]!=0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public void printBoard()
{
    System.out.print(board[0][0] + " " + board[0][1] + " " + board[0][2]);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(board[1][0] + " " + board[1][1] + " " + board[1][2]);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(board[2][0] + " " + board[2][1] + " " + board[2][2]);
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

**And now the solver class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solver
{
ArrayList<Board> list;
int steps;

public Solver()
{
    list = new ArrayList<Board>();
    steps = 0;
}

public Board SwapStates(Board b, int a[][], int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2)
{
    int temp = a[r1][c1];
    a[r1][c1] = a[r2][c2];
    a[r2][c2] = temp;

    return b;
}

//Find the board in ArrayList according the number of states out of order
public Board findBoard(int num)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(num == list.get(i).states_out_of_order())
        {
            return list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

//Choose the puzzle state with minimum states that are out of order
public int min()
{
    int n = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(list.get(i).states_out_of_order() < n)
        {
            n = list.get(i).states_out_of_order();
        }
    }
    return n;
}

//Find the board in ArrayList and remove it
public void matchRemove(Board b)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(b == list.get(i))
        {
            list.remove(list.get(i));
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void Hamming(Board b)
{
    boolean solved = b.GoalStateCheck();

    while(!solved)
    {
        if(b.board[0][0] == 0)
        {
            //Pointer to original board
            final Board ptr = b;

            Board b1 = ptr;
            Board b2 = ptr;

            //Check move #1 from original state
            b1 = SwapStates(b1, b1.board,0,0,0,1);

            //Check move #2 from original state
            //Problem is that it is not swapping ptr but rather its swapping b1. why?
            b2 = SwapStates(b2, b2.board,0,0,1,0);

            //Add the moves to the Arraylist
            list.add(b1);
            list.add(b2);

            //Find the board with minimum number of states out of order and remove it frm list
            int n = min();
            Board temp = findBoard(n);
            matchRemove(temp);

            //Assign removed board as optimum move
            b = temp;
            steps++;
            b.printBoard();
        }

        else if(b.board[0][1] == 0)
        {

        }

        else if(b.board[0][2] == 0)
        {

        }

        else if(b.board[1][0] == 0)
        {

        }

        else if(b.board[1][1] == 0)
        {

        }

        else if(b.board[1][2] == 0)
        {

        }

        else if(b.board[2][0] == 0)
        {

        }

        else if(b.board[2][1] == 0)
        {

        }

        else if(b.board[2][2] == 0)
        {

        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Board is not in its proper form");
            break;
        }
    }
    /*System.out.println("Goal State has been achieved!!");
    System.out.println("It took " + steps + " moves");
    b.printBoard();*/
}
}
```

In the Hamming function of my Solver class at the first if statement i have this line

```
final Board ptr = b;
Board b1 = ptr;
Board b2 = ptr;
```

However when at these two lines:

```
            //Check move #1 from original state
            b1 = SwapStates(b1, b1.board,0,0,0,1);

            //Check move #2 from original state
            //Problem is that it is not swapping ptr but rather its swapping b1. why?
            b2 = SwapStates(b2, b2.board,0,0,1,0);
```

b2 is using the swapped state of b1 instead of the original ptr which i want to use. why?

Comment: ptr, b1 and b2 are the same object. You may want to read about how references work in Java, and about object mutability.

Answer (score 1):

When you've written

```
final Board ptr = b;
Board b1 = ptr;
Board b2 = ptr;
```

You **did not** create an immutable copy of `b` called `ptr` and two mutable copies of `ptr` called `b1` and `b2`.

You simply created 3 references to the same object. Any modification on the object using any of the 4 references will end up affecting the object in the same way and thus, change the visible state for all 4 references.

What you should do is add a `public Board copy()` method in your board class which would return another instance of Board (using a `new Board()` and copying values) and change your code by :

```
final Board ptr = b.copy(); // but is there any sense to use ptr rather than b ?
Board b1 = ptr.copy();
Board b2 = ptr.copy();
```

Comment: Yes that works. I also solved the problem by creating a copy constructor.